# Delegate declaration dilemma

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, cocoa-design-patterns

I'm confused - I cannot understand what is the delegate is for?

The Application Delegate which is created by default is understandable, but in some cases I've seen something like this:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UIPageControl *pageControl;
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
    BOOL pageControlUsed;
}

//...

@end
```

What is the `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` for?

How does it work and why is it used?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<UIScrollViewDelegate>` is saying that the class *conforms to* the `UIScrollViewDelegate` ***protocol***.

What this really means is that the class must implement all of the required methods defined within the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol. Simple as that.

You can conform your class to multiple protocols if you like:

```
@implementation MyClass : UIViewController <SomeProtocol, SomeOtherProtocol>
```

The purpose of conforming a class to a protocol is to a) declare the type as a conformant of the protocol, so you can now categorize this type under `id <SomeProtocol>`, which is better for delegate objects that objects of this class may belong to, and b) It tells the compiler to not warn you that the implemented methods are not declared in the header file, because your class conforms to the protocol.

Here's an example:

Printable.h

```
@protocol Printable

 - (void) print:(Printer *) printer;

@end
```

Document.h

```
#import "Printable.h"
@interface Document : NSObject <Printable> {
   //ivars omitted for brevity, there are sure to be many of these :)
}
@end
```

Document.m

```
@implementation Document

   //probably tons of code here..

#pragma mark Printable methods

   - (void) print: (Printer *) printer {
       //do awesome print job stuff here...
   }

@end
```

You could *then* have multiple objects that conform to the `Printable` protocol, which could then be used as an instance variable in, say, a `PrintJob` object:

```
@interface PrintJob : NSObject {
   id <Printable> target;
   Printer *printer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id <Printable> target;

- (id) initWithPrinter:(Printer *) print;
- (void) start;

@end

@implementation PrintJob 

@synthesize target; 

- (id) initWithPrinter:(Printer *) print andTarget:(id<Printable>) targ {
   if((self = [super init])) {
      printer = print;
      self.target = targ;
   }
   return self;
}

- (void) start {
   [target print:printer]; //invoke print on the target, which we know conforms to Printable
}

- (void) dealloc {
   [target release];
   [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: To further clarify Jacob's response... The reason you would use a delegate would be to assign a class to do the handling of specific tasks the UIScrollView object relies on to do it's job properly. In laymen terms you could think of it as a a personal assistant. A boss is too busy to care about how lunch is ordered, so he has a delegate (his secretary or such) which he calls upon to order lunch for his team in an important meeting. He simply says "Hey Judy, we need lunch for 5 people, here is what they want", Judy then takes that information and does whatever needs to be done to get the lunch.

Comment: Thanks Jacob and Flash84x.... :)

one more request...can u please provide me some basic code using these type of protocols??

The logic is clear..i just wanna knw how to use it... :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to understand the [Delegate Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern). It is a core pattern used by iphone/ipad applications and if you don't understand it you will not get far. The link to wikipedia I just used outlines the pattern and gives examples of it's use including Objective C. That would be a good place to get started. Also look at take a look at the [Overview tutorial from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/01_Overview.html) which is specific to the iPhone and also discusses the Delegate pattern.